# Java Random : How to return int value with non significative 0

Tags: java, random

I need to get a random value between 0 and 100 in String format.

I use Random class, but when i cast the result in String, the non significative 0 are not kepped.

```
 sb.append((rand.nextInt(99)));
```

Is there a method in StringBuilder or Random for force the result with this 0 ?

Comment: What would you expect `Random` to do here? It just returns an `int`, and there's no notion of an `int` having a difference between 1, 01, or 001. I suspect you want to format the integer as a string first, then append that string to the `StringBuilder`. So the next thing to research is "formatting integers as strings in Java".

Comment: I need to generate a French phone number with 0X YY YY YY YY format. X is between 0 and 7, NN are number between 0 and 99 with significative 0.

But with this command, StringBuilder don't add these 0 ...

Comment: No sorry, my previous post was incomplter. See above

Comment: @Broshet I don't really see how that invalidates the answers in the link I mentioned. `sb.append(String.format("%02d", rand.nextInt(99)));` always appends two digits. When the random number is less than 10, it will prepend a `0`.

Comment: *FYI:* `nextInt(99)` generates a number in range 0-98 *(both inclusive)*, not a number "between 0 and 100", where it is unspecified whether 0 and 100 are considered "between" too. If yes, range would be 0-100, if no range would be 1-99. None of this generates a number in range 0-99, which is what I think you're looking for.

Comment: That's it: I want get the numbers between 0 and 99 inclusive, i will use range 0-100. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked: Is there a method in StringBuilder or Random for force the result with this 0 ?

Answer: No. You need to research for String formatting options. One options is `String.format()`.

Example:

```
String formatted = String.format("%03d", rand.nextInt(99));
sb.append( formatted );
```

Comment: Sure, but this method allways add a 0 even number is greater than 10 ? Should I have to test lenght each time ? (I execute this traitement 4 time in a hurge data)

Comment: @Broshet did you actually try to run the code?

Comment: Yes, the length is 3

Comment: @Broshet in the question you talk about numbers up to 100 so Victor assumed that there have to be 3 numbers. Just change it to `"%02d"` to get 2 numbers.

Comment: @Broshet Do your research for String.format at google or SO, test the code. If you find errors, you can open a new question with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format`:

```
public class FormatExample {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        int i = 4;
        int j = 44;
        int k = 102;
        String str1 = String.format("%03d", i);  
        String str2 = String.format("%03d", j);  
        String str3 = String.format("%03d", k); 

        System.out.println(str1);  
        System.out.println(str2);  
        System.out.println(str3);  
    }  
}
```

Prints:

```
004
044
102
```

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the syntax. This is what I was looking for. Thank you all for your help. My explanation was ambiguous, it was 2 digits (00 to 99)